# Laragon cannot conect to database: empty user

Tags: mysql, environment-variables, laragon

So my Laragon project throws an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to
>   database 'qa'

While in my .env file I have

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=qa
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

There is no password in my database, that's correct, but why does the system (as I can judge from the error) ignore the database username?

Answer (score 0):

try to **clear the cache**
$ php artisan cache:clear
and try to open **the safe mode** for db using the laragon terminal by typing
$ mysqld  --tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK

**else** try to create another db with another user and upgrade all the privilege for this user and it will be running.